# How to create this Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule?

Tags: magento

Offers FREE SHIPPING only to products with a product attribute (in_stock) to YES and the subtotal of such items must be greater than $99. Rules apply to matching items only.

```
For example,

item A $80 in stock
item B $20 in stock
Results: FREE SHIPPING

item A $80 in stock
item B $20 in stock
item C $30 out of stock
Results: SHIPPING COST FOR ITEM C ONLY

item A $100 in stock
Results: FREE SHIPPING

item C $30 out of stock
item A $80 in stock
RESULTS: SHIPPING COST FOR BOTH item A and C.
```

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Answer (score 0):

hi please make this type rules for this functionality, you change just use product attribute 'stock-availability' in condition with sku-id's.

you will check rules here:-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7t8c5qiznkjgz13/Free%20Shipping%20for%20Single%20Product%20Using%20Shopping%20Cart%20Price%20Rules.docx?dl=0